# Jsoup, Reddit, OAuth2, and 429 HTTP Errors

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, jsoup, reddit, http-status-code-429

So I'm trying to write an executable JAR for a small subreddit I run.

I have a post that Jsoup connects to and reads all the URLs on that page. In another method, it then connects to all those URLs (that are just comments on the post) and gets the HTML from the comments and saves them to a HashMap.

This is great however I am getting a 429 HTTP Error. So to resolve this, I added a short 5 second wait. Now I'm getting a `SocketTimeoutException` "Read timed out". Once I lowered the time down to 3 seconds, I was bouncing between the two.

Now I run a few Reddit bots with Python and I'm able to make a lot more requests than what I'm doing here. I actually have a single bot that makes thousands of requests every minute. So I know it's possible to make these requests.

My question essentially is, how am I able to make multiple requests to Reddit and avoid the 429 HTTP Error? I'm using Jsoup to connect and read the HTML.

While I'm sure connecting to Reddit via. their OAuth2 API will fix the issues, I have no idea how to actually use OAuth2 in Java (I actually use a wrapper in Python so it's fair to say I don't know at all) and I don't know how to then use that with Jsoup.

Answer (score 0):

> My question essentially is, how am I able to make multiple requests to Reddit and avoid the 429 HTTP Error?

You answer this yourself:

> While I'm sure connecting to Reddit via. their OAuth2 API will fix the issues,

As specified in [the API documentation](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/API), you get twice as many requests per second if authenticated using OAuth.

Have you looked around for examples on how to handle OAuth flows in Java?

You might also find it easier to use one of [the wrapper](https://github.com/thatJavaNerd/JRAW) [libraries](https://github.com/jReddit/jReddit) for Java, instead of handling all this yourself.

Comment: JRAW is apparently unstable. jReddit is an option though. I've worked up a temp fix by appending `.api` to the URL which helps me in this situation. I haven't thoroughly looked around for OAuth examples in Java but I thought there may have been a problem if I was also using Jsoup to connect to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Just set header and you can easily pass it

```
User-Agent: super happy flair bot by /u/spladug
```